# Alternative for Landing Page

Tags: synonyms

In the web design world a Landing Page is typically the first page that you land on in a website that is quite long and shows you the majority of the websites information. Typically used to sell a product or service.

I like this style for an Excel report in which all the analytics, tables etc are on one sheet which extends downs in a similar fashion to a Landing Page, I don't want to call it a Landing Page or Landing Page Report unless I really have to as the terms is linked to website. Is there an alternative or general such term.

Comment: I've rarely heard this called anything other than a "home page", but for a more authoritative answer ask on a computer-oriented site like StackOverflow or SuperUser.

Comment: Is your first tab a Summary, Quick View, or Dashboard?

Comment: @HotLicks A home page would be on the full website a Landing Page is typically a standalone page selling a single product or service.

Comment: @YosefBaskin The would only be one tab and it would be called anything like Summary, Report, Overview, Dashboard, but it the word for single page report that I think I am looking for.

Comment: @Naz, in business writing we would call what you are describing an "Executive Summary."

Answer (score 1):

I echo what @HotLicks said, the first thing that came to mind for me was a "home page."

My understanding is that the phrase "landing page" is more commonly the web developer side phrase and "home page" is more the consumer side.

For example, when talking to a web developer, a manager might ask that they add a new feature to the *landing page*. A consumer might notice a new phone for sale after visiting a website's *home page*.

In both cases, it is clear that both are referring to the first page of the website (the first page that contains summarily constructed information). In this case, the difference is the background of the speaker who is using the word.

Comment: Was a programmer for 40 years and rarely if ever heard "landing page".  (Though I wasn't in the thick of web page development.)

Comment: @HotLicks, I should clarify that I am referring specifically to web development, my bad, will edit this now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Ethan Landing Page really has two definitions the first is the first page that you visit on a website from a search (not necessarily the home page), the second is a standalone website that consists of only one page in that sense the Landing Page is more a marketing concept.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to spreadsheets I have seen *switchboard* used when there are buttons for the user to choose from that take them to different forms.

As others have said, a *home page*, or *main page* is commonly used and recognized.

Wikipedia uses *disambiguation* for their pages that list links to separate pages that all share a common name, example: [Cat (disambiguation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(disambiguation)).

It all depends on your specific usage and context, but I believe *home page* is probably the best fit and most recognized.